# Mixture of shutdown() and shutdownNow()

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

[ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) inherits two methods from the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), [shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) and [shutdownNow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--). The difference between them:

> `shutdown` initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>
> `shutdownNow` attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

Now I want to halt processing of waiting tasks while I don't want to interrupt currently executing tasks. I can't interrupt the threads because third party libraries are involved and they don't deal well with interrupts :-( But I need to cancel [scheduled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) tasks, that are not currently executing since most of them are scheduled in an hour or so.

What's the best way to deal with this? What options Do I have?

Comment: A combination of `shutdown` and [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) must do the trick.

Comment: @marcospereira `awaitTermination` will wait until the last scheduled task is finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like calling [setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy-boolean-) on your executor should do the trick:

> Sets the policy on whether to execute existing delayed tasks even when
>   this executor has been shutdown. In this case, these tasks will only
>   terminate upon shutdownNow, or after setting the policy to false when
>   already shutdown. This value is by default true.

Since it's `true` by default, these tasks are executed. If you set it to `false`, they shouldn't be executed any more. This shouldn't be confused with *submitted* tasks which the docs you quote refer to. They are just waiting in the queue to be executed right away, when there is a free worker.

Comment: Yes, that works great! I forgot this method as it belongs to `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(int)` returns the `ScheduledExecutorService` interface. Now I create the STPE myself. Thanks!